# mvn clean install throwing build failure error

Tags: maven

I am new to maven. I recently cloned a repository from GIT and saved it in a location on my machine. I have git bash, i am cd'ing to the location where i saved my code and trying to execute the `mvn clean install` command. but i am seeing the below error. It is unable to locate POM files. How can I solve this problem?. I have tried deleting the code and cloning again but that has not helped.

[image]

Below is the POM file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.XXXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX-XXX</artifactId>
    <version>sprint1506-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>XXX-XXX</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <description>
        This is the Mega pom to combine XXX, XXX
        and XXX projects in a single reactor.
        </description>
    <modules>
        <module>wesp</module>
        <module>transite</module>
                <module>sassy</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: it says that it cannot find (resolve) jasmine-maven-plugin (or one of its dependencies). it cannot find it in the maven repo. maybe you should first make sure you get this plugin on your local repo (you can fork it and build it)

Comment: Could you share the project and/or the pom?

Comment: It is not a pom issue, it is a connection issue, probably firewall or proxy. In case of a proxy, please read http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html . In case of the firewall, ensure the java has an outbound rule for 443.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1 : Build it by your own

As OhadR said, your local repository does not contain the jasmine-maven-plugin, so :

1. Clone the jasmine-maven-plugin repo (`git clone git@github.com:searls/jasmine-maven-plugin.git`)
2. Build this plugin with `mvn install`command
3. Build the project you cloned with `mvn install` command

### Solution 2

If you don't want to rely on your own build, try to add the Sonatype repository to your pom, as an external source. Looking at the plugin jasmine-maven-plugin's pom, it appears that they deploy it on OSS repo.

```xml
<project ...>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>OSS</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was fixed when i updated the settings.xml file in `apache-maven-3.3.3\conf`  folder. I had to configure my login credentials in the settings.xml file for the build to complete. I also had to point my .m2/repository directory to the `<localRepository>` tag inside the settings.xml file for the build to commence. Thanks everyone for the inputs.

Below are the fields which I changed inside the settings.xml file ( highlighted in bold):

```
  ****<localRepository>C:\Users\XXX\.m2\repository</localRepository>****



  <proxies>
              <proxy>
                     <id>XXXX</id>
                     <active>true</active>
                     <protocol>http</protocol>
                     <host>proxy.kdc.XXXXX.com</host>
                     <port>8099</port>
                     **<username>XXX</username>**
                     **<password>XXXX</password>**
                     <nonProxyHosts>*.XXXXX.com</nonProxyHosts>
              </proxy>
       </proxies>
```